# xcode shortcut preferences not saved

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I have a problem with my Xcode (4.3.3) : I have created a new Command Sets to have personal shortcuts. All works fine until I leave the application.

When I close Xcode (normally), all my personal shortcuts are lost.
My new Command Sets is still here, but the shortcuts are the same as the Default Command Sets.

Does anyone know something about this weird behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into key conflicts and then deleting them all.  I went in to delete them all and then it started saving.  Hope it works.